# coercive bilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Here I want to prove the uniqueness of the weak solution for the homogeneous Dirichlet boundary value problem:

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}3u′′ − 2u′ + 3u = f \\
 u(0) = u(1) = 0\\ 
 \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*} 
for any given $f ∈ C(\bar{I})$ on $I = (0, 1)$ by using Lax-Milgram lemma. So first I have to show the map which is defined by $\alpha : H^1(I) × H^1(I) → \mathbb{R},$
$$\alpha(f, g) = \int_I(3f′g′ − f′g − fg′ + 3fg)$$
 is bounded, symmetric and coercive bilinear form. But I couldn't go further the coercive part. Could somebody please give me a hint?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know a relation between $\alpha$ and your boundary value problem?

Comment: @ gerw.. I got an idea and I edited the question.

Comment: Your weak formulation is off. It should read $-2\,f' \, g$ instead of $-f'\,g-f\,g'$. And it is sufficient to prove coercivity on $H_0^1(I)$. Symmetry is not needed for Lax-Milgram.

Comment: ..I see, thanks!

Comment: If you have solved your problem, you can post your solution as an answer.